# probability given standard deviation and mean using excel norm.dist function

Tags: probability

I don't know if this is the right sub for this ,but I can find the probability something is less than i.e. NORMDIST $( \mathrm { x } ,$ mean, standard deviation, cumulative) but what if I want to find it is less than or equal to? is this formula sufficient ?

Comment: The normal distribution is a continuous distribution.  In such cases you have that $Pr(X\leq k) = Pr(X<k)$ and that $Pr(X=k)=0$.  That is not to say that it is "impossible" in the literal sense for a particular number to be the result of a continuous random variable, but rather it is so unlikely to happen that the only feasible probability that we can assign it occurring is zero.

Comment: thanks for the clarification